# Openstack centos qcow2 public image login

Tags: centos, openstack

I have launched an instance in openstack with centos 7 qcow2 public image.

I am able to boot it but unfortunately, the login is not working.

By default, Centos images are with user centos and no password but they are not working.

I have downloaded Centos from https://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/obtain-images.html

Any suggestion on this?

Comment: "not working" is not a problem description. Please edit your question and describe how you log on, and what happens when you try.

Answer (score 0):

Where your `no password` comes from? Its the user `centos` yes, but the password-login of these images is completely disabled (except Cirros). You have to register an public ssh-key in your openstack-account, which is loaded in the VM by Cloud-init while creating the VM and then you have to use the ssh-key to access the VM.

But maybe I do not understand your question correctly and you mean, that you already used an ssh-key instead of a password. In this case, have you enabled the port 22 for the ssh-access in the security groups within your openstack-account? Per default all incoming port (inclusive ssh) are blocked by these rules.